# Math.Random() selects some more when selecting items an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, random, probability

I want to choose one of the items I have according to the possibilities( according square p).

For this;

```
for (let sec_index = 0; sec_index < 1000;) { //i want select 1000 pcs
    var random_item_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * posts_array.length); //select random item and return index number
    var random_item = posts_array[random_item_num]; //return random item key.
    var random_item_real_prob = prob_map[random_item]; //return random item's p ,  0.56489321 etc... '.
    var random_item_prob = Math.pow(random_item_real_prob, 2) * s_loc; //s_loc is a coefficient
    var random_sayi = Math.random(); //new random number
    if (random_sayi<random_item_prob) {
        selection_array[sec_index] = random_item; // return [[1: id][2:id]......]
        selection_count[random_item_prob]++; //return [[p : 1] [other p : 10] ......]
        sec_index++;
    }
}
```

These codes is still work.

**BUT ;**
p , selection count in 1000

[image: p , selection count in 1000]

As you will see here, it makes too much choice for some possibilities. This repeats every time. Although their positions in Array are constantly changing, the result is the same.

Is that a mathematical problem?

Thank You!

Comment: I am highly confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: Why does it make more choices for certain probabilty? You can see this on the picture.

Comment: There is something unusual about how you are selecting numbers, since you only make 1000 attempts to choose a number, but each time you only select a number with relatively low probability.  Thus, I'd expect you to have many non-updated indexes in selection_array (and the sum of all values in selection_count to be far less than 1000).  Is this the behavior you expect and are seeing?  (Likewise, what is the value of s_loc?)

Comment: Also, where is random_item_prob1 defined?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Should `random_item_prob1` be `random_item_prob`?

Comment: thank you for comment. selection array and selection count for just  have to see the results. They're not functional.
But before the process starts, I reset all of them. And s_loc to increase the possibility of election. a coefficient that maximizes the highest probability in the list to 1.(every time  highest p * s_loc < 1)

Comment: random_item_prob1 is a misspellings . It was wrong when i posted it. It works in code.

Comment: Random numbers tend to clump, they won't be distributed evenly.

Comment: So how do we explain the same number of clump in each trial?

Comment: First of all thanks to everyone. Problem was solved. In contrast to organic use, I had a number of "p" that calculate hand-made some counts. Some possibilities are exactly the same. therefore the number of selections corresponding to the same ``` random_item_prob``` in the ``` selection_count```array are combined. In seconds, time variables are effective in calculating "p". In real use, there is no possibility of such a situation.